# How to transpose scripting dictionary keys and retain "05" and "5" as two distinct values?

Tags: excel, vba, distinct-values, scripting.dictionary

I created a table to include/exclude distinct values from a larger dataset. This table is made with a scripting dictionary.

The dataset could contain numeric values as a parameter which should be considered as a textual value.
Example: "05" and "5" should be considered as two distinct values.

The scripting dictionary saves the two values as two distinct values but when I use the Application.Transpose code for the keys the keys are considered as one value ("5").

**Is there a way to paste the keys as two distinct values?**
I've tried to add a single quote (`'`) in front of the relevant data but this didn't appear in the keys.

```vb
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Dim d As Object, c As Variant, j As Long, lr As Long
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Worksheets("DATASET").Activate
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, aCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    c = Range(Cells(1, aCell.Column).Address(), Cells(lr, aCell.Column).Address())
    For j = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
        d(c(j, 1)) = 1
    Next j

    Targetrange.Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `Targetrange` has the number format `General` it will consider the string `05` as a number and convert it to `5`.

So either change your number format to text before you add the values:

```
Targetrange.NumberFormat = "@"
Targetrange.Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
```

or add a `'` in the dictionary before every entry:

```
d("'" & c(j, 1)) = 1
```

---

Off topic note:

the `Range()` method can take cells and does not need addresses so you can remove `.Address()` from

```
Range(Cells(1, aCell.Column).Address(), Cells(lr, aCell.Column).Address())
```

and just write

```
 Range(Cells(1, aCell.Column), Cells(lr, aCell.Column))
```

or even shorter:

```
 Cells(1, aCell.Column).Resize(RowSize:=lr)
```

if it does not begin in row `1` but row `n` then it is

```
 Cells(n, aCell.Column).Resize(RowSize:=lr - (n - 1))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I did but i need more reputation.

Comment: @Fabian_W for up-voting you need reputation, but accepting it should work without reputation after 1 hour at least.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, aCell As Range, TargetRange As Range
    Dim ar As Variant, lr As Long, j As Long, c As Integer
    
    Dim d As Object, key As String
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set ws = Worksheets("DATASET")
    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A1") ' change
        c = aCell.Column
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
        ar = .Cells(1, c).Resize(lr).Value2
    End With

    For j = 1 To UBound(ar)
        key = Trim(ar(j, 1))
        If Len(key) > 0 Then
            d(key) = 1
        End If
    Next

    Set TargetRange = Sheet2.Range("A1") ' change
    With TargetRange.Resize(d.Count)
        .NumberFormat = "@" ' text
        .Value2 = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
    End With
    MsgBox d.Count & " keys in d"

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Column` is of type `Long` therefore `c` must be of the same type.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Why ? `Range("XFD1").Column` is 16,384 , integer limit is 32,767

Comment: Because `Debug.Print TypeName(Range("XFD1").Column)` says it is `Long`. And if you don't use the same type you have implicit type conversions all over your code. Actually I recommend **always** to use `Long` instead of `Integer` as there is no benefit in using `Integer`. You might want to read why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520).

Comment: The first `' change` is inaccurate. You could fix it with something like `Dim r as long: r = aCell.Row` ... `ar = .Cells(r, c).Resize(lr - r + 1).Value2`. Also, I prefer `.Rows.Count`.

Comment: @VBasic2008  `c = Range(Cells(1, aCell.Column), etc` so is not dependent on `aCell.row`.

Comment: Your focus should be on `.Cells(1, c)`. If e.g. the user chooses the cell `A3`, then the array will, after the resize, also contain the values from `A1:A2`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes, but that is how the posted code is written and I am not changing it.

Comment: You don't have to, but it's working correctly only for the first row so you should at least remove the comment or change it to (`' change column`).

Comment: @VBasic I think you misunderstood. I am not changing the way in which the code snippet posted in the question works, which is to start at row 1 regardless of what `aCell.row` is.